# WooCommerce Cart showing Empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wooocmmerce cart is showing empty after adding product in cart.Cart count increase 0 to 1 but after 2 or 3 seconds again it's showing empty what is the problem.please somebody help me.

For testing purpose I am using this code to  show item count and amout

```
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

it's showing both the things for 3 seconds after that again it goes blank

here is the url

http://ec2-54-69-172-133.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/mbox1/?product=customization

Thank you

Comment: Showing some errors in console, I think it will effect .

Comment: when I am clicking on add to cart button it is showing price and count also but after 3 second again count/amount goes to blank I don't know what is happening please suggest something